# pyQt GUI close current window using python

Tags: pyqt4

I have two python files, out of which the first one is a home window of Gui and the second file is an input window.I  make an object of the second window in the first file and when I press the button on the first window it shifts me to the second window and when I want to exit the second window than the first window also get an exit. So how I am able to close the second window without affecting the first one.
Please help me to seek out my problem.

This is my homewindow code:

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
from close import Ui_Form

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_home(object):
    def **init**(self):
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.home = QtGui.QWidget() 
        self.setupUi(self.home)
        self.home.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

```
def setupUi(self, home):
    home.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("home"))
    home.resize(475, 300)
    self.pushButton_OK = QtGui.QPushButton(home)
    self.pushButton_OK.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 200, 99, 27))
    self.pushButton_OK.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_OK"))
    self.pushButton_OK.clicked.connect(self.closeWindow)
    self.label = QtGui.QLabel(home)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 30, 191, 91))
    self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))

    self.retranslateUi(home)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(home)

def retranslateUi(self, home):
    home.setWindowTitle(_translate("home", "Form", None))
    self.pushButton_OK.setText(_translate("home", "Ok", None))
    self.label.setText(_translate("home", "              HOME WINDOW", None))

def closeWindow(self):
     self.ui=Ui_Form()
```

ui=Ui_home()

This is my close window code:

```
    return s
```

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):
    def **init**(self):

```
    self.closeWindow = QtGui.QWidget()
    self.setupUi(self.closeWindow )
    self.closeWindow.show()
def setupUi(self, Form):
    Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
    Form.resize(400, 300)
    self.pushButton_close = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
    self.pushButton_close.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 180, 99, 27))
    self.pushButton_close.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_close"))
    self.pushButton_close.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)

    self.retranslateUi(Form)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

def retranslateUi(self, Form):
    Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
    self.pushButton_close.setText(_translate("Form", "close", None))
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: Know sir I have edited but when i moved to the second window then by pressing exit button i want to close it not hide it .